# Text length + table-cell + percentage height - what is going on here?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-tables

I have a div using `display: table-cell` which contains a child div... both use percentage-based dimensions. When that child div contains more than a certain amount of text (depending on font-size), it ignores its height rule.

[Here's an isolated test-case](http://jsfiddle.net/mSPx8/)

Clicking the "toggle text" button will demonstrate the issue. Its more pronounced in Chrome & Safari but Firefox also exhibits the issue.

I would expect the `.child` div's height to be 40px... but instead it is roughly 290px (in Chrome & Safari). Likewise, `.table` should have a height of 240px.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="child">
                    <div class="child-inner">
                        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna, Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.083333333333333%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

.table-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0%;
    height: 16.666666666%;
    width: 93.75%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.child-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `display:table`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XuxCT/1/ that's how I would do your CSS and HTML, it still could be better but it should work on all browsers.

Comment: display: table b/c I need to support vertical alignment of child elements

Comment: Well, you begin with an absolutely positioned div that has a height of 100%. 100% of what? Absolutely positioned elements don't have a parent that they can base their dimensions on. And the rest is all percentages, so the browsers just have to guess what they need to do.

Comment: Oh, if you click "toggle text" a second time, the text is not toggled back to what it was initially.

Comment: In this case, the containing block should be ".main" (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details). Though setting a px-based value on ".child" has the same effect as toggling the text. Interestingly, toggling between px and % does something similar to toggling text... but the weird thing is that you can't get back to the original state.

Comment: Also, there appears to be some magic combination of character count and font-size that causes ".child" to demonstrate the issue when toggling text. Using the fiddle I made, toggling the text jumps between the correct (40px) and incorrect (270px) heights on chrome and safari (Firefox uses something like 52px initially and thus jumps from that to 40px and back). My test case doesnt trigger the issue on mobile safari... but it could be made to by trimming a bit more text.

Answer (score 1):

I tried wrapping the growing element in a div that is using absolute positioning, it seemed to have the effect you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/fschwiet/2RgPV/.  See the "fixme" div that was added.  The idea is that the fixme div kind of seals whatever is happening within it from whatever table logic lives outside.

```
.fixme {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks!... but I'd expect the end result should be div.child with height of 40px (computed). OR! barring that, a better understanding of what rule(s) i'm breaking...if that makes *any* sense (>_<)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the padding on `.child-inner` is having adverse affects. I removed the padding and it now respects the height. http://jsfiddle.net/cwardzala/Z27S9/1/

```
.child-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: hehe... unfortunately, you've just gone below the magic trigger. if you add in some more text (ex: "Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor." ), you'll see the weirdness return. thanks tho!